# I want to access age from obj. how can I do this

Tags: javascript

I want to access age from obj. how can I do this.

```
const obj={
     data:'key=werth, age=23 ,key=wrte, age=34, key=gfhhf,age=45'
 }
let obj2=JSON.parse(obj.data);
console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON. JSON would look like this: `{"key": "werth", "age": 23}`

Comment: Why not just have your object as `obj: { data: { key: 'werth', age: 23 } }` and then you could just get the age with `obj.data.age`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this JSON, the way to access age would be slightly different as age is not a property of obj. You can access data which will give you a string and then from that you can access age, like this:

```
   const age = obj.data.split(',')[1].split('=')[1]
```

Comment: your code worked when we have single age value what if I have multiple age value